# Jetpack Compose: hasExpandedState in SheetState

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-modalbottomsheet

I am creating my first decent app on compose and I need your help with SheetState to make ModalBottomSheet. I want this modal bottom sheet to be only on hidden and partially expanded state.

```
val hasExpandedState: Boolean
        get() = swipeableState.hasAnchorForValue(Expanded)
```

SheetState class has such a variable hasExpandedState, which as I understood could help me, but it is actually a value, so it's value couldn't be  changed in my code. How to make ModalBottomSheet only in such states, is this hasExpandedState needed?

hasExpandedState can not be reassigned

Answer (score 0):

The expanded state can be disabled by modifying the `confirmValueChange` parameter of the ModalBottomSheet state. The following code allows the sheet value to be set only to a hidden or partially expanded.

```kotlin
val sheetState = rememberModalBottomSheetState(
    confirmValueChange = { sheetValue ->

        // Confirm a value change only if the sheet value
        // is hidden or partially expanded.

        sheetValue == SheetValue.Hidden
            || sheetValue == SheetValue.PartiallyExpanded

    }
)
```

The `partialExpand()` function will animate the ModalBottomSheet to a partially expanded state when invoked. Keep in mind that this function is a suspend function, which means that it has to be invoked inside a coroutine context. It can be done by launching a coroutine and calling the function.

```kotlin
var isBottomSheetVisible by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()

Button(
    onClick = {
        coroutineScope.launch {
            isBottomSheetVisible = true
            sheetState.partialExpand()
        }
    }
) {
    Text(text = "Expand Partially")
}
```

The `hide()` function will animate the ModalBottomSheet to a hidden state when invoked. This function is also a suspend function and it requires a coroutine context. Also, it's important to update the state which is associated with the visibility of the ModalBottomSheet composable, by wrapping it inside an `invokeOnCompletion` block, which will be executed as soon as the `sheetState.hide()` execution is completed. It's recommended to include it since `hide()` function animates the state.

```kotlin
Button(
    onClick = {
        coroutineScope
            .launch { sheetState.hide() }
            .invokeOnCompletion { isBottomSheetVisible = false }
    }
) {
    Text(text = "Hide")
}
```

Here is an example of a ModalBottomSheet implementation:

```kotlin
// The conditional state controlling the [ModalBottomSheet]
// composable visibility.
var isBottomSheetVisible by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

// The coroutine scope required for partially expanding / hiding
// the [ModalBottomSheet].
val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()

// The actual state of the [ModalBottomSheet].
val sheetState = rememberModalBottomSheetState(
    confirmValueChange = { sheetValue ->

        // Confirm a value change only if the sheet value
        // is hidden or partially expanded.

        sheetValue == SheetValue.Hidden
                || sheetValue == SheetValue.PartiallyExpanded

    }
)

Surface(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
) {

    Box(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
    ) {

        Button(
            modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.Center),
            onClick = {

                // Partially expand the [ModalBottomSheet] by using
                // the [coroutineScope] and launching a coroutine.

                coroutineScope.launch {
                    isBottomSheetVisible = true
                    sheetState.partialExpand()
                }

            }
        ) {
            Text(text = "Show")
        }

        // Controlling the [ModalBottomSheet] composable visibility
        // by using the [isBottomSheetVisible] conditional state.
        if (isBottomSheetVisible) {

            ModalBottomSheet(
                onDismissRequest = { isBottomSheetVisible = false },
                sheetState = sheetState
            ) {

                Button(
                    modifier = Modifier,
                    onClick = {

                        // Hide the [ModalBottomSheet] by using
                        // the [coroutineScope] to launch a coroutine
                        // and update the [isBottomSheetVisible]
                        // conditional state when the coroutine is finished.

                        coroutineScope
                            .launch { sheetState.hide() }
                            .invokeOnCompletion { isBottomSheetVisible = false }

                    }
                ) {
                    Text(text = "Hide")
                }

                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))

            }

        }

    }

}
```

I highly recommend checking out the *[Official Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/package-summary#ModalBottomSheet(kotlin.Function0,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,androidx.compose.material3.SheetState,androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Shape,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,kotlin.Function0,androidx.compose.foundation.layout.WindowInsets,androidx.compose.material3.ModalBottomSheetProperties,kotlin.Function1)).*